# Abbreviate php if/or statement

Tags: php

is there a way to abbreviate the following?

```
if ($chk == 1 || $chk == 3 || $chk == 5 || $chk == 7){
do some stuff
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: check ou the edit titled "or some thing logic"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (in_array($chk, array(1, 3, 5, 7))) ...
```

Or, if you plan to include if-elseif-cascades, use switch statement:

```
switch($chk)
{
  case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: 
    do_something();
    break; 
  case 10: case 30: case 50: case 70: 
    do_something_else();
    break; 
  default: 
    do_default();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use only uneven numbers, you could check the value. If the value is uneven, then the function will be executed

```
$unevenNumbers=array(1,2,3,4,5,7);

foreach($unevenNumbers as $nbr){
    if( $nbr % 2 !== 0){
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**if you are looking odd!**

```
if (!(($chk % 2)==0)  // can use if($chk&1) instead
{
 //odd acess
}
 else
{
 //even stuff
}
```

**or**

```
if($num&1) 
{
    //odd stuff
} 
else 
{
    //even stuff
}
```

**or some thing logic**

```
if($num&1) 
{
    //odd stuff

      if($num>=1 && $num<=7)
                  {//your special stuff 
                  }
} 
else 
{
    //even stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operators.

```
in_array($chk, array(1, 3, 5, 7)) ? /* Do some stuff*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 3, 5, 7);
if (in_array($chk, $arr)) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```